# How to sort a list based on average outcomes

Tags: sorting, ranking, bins

I have a list of N objects (easily conceptualized as sports teams), and I'd like to sort them based on their average success rate (i.e., win or loss) when paired up against each of the other N-1 objects. So, in the least efficient algorithm, I would just pair each object up with every other object, measure the outcome, and then rank the objects by their relative win percentage.

This is N*(N+1)/2 comparisons if I assess each pairwise outcome, which is ok for small N, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to sort such data without having to consider all pairwise comparisons. I should also add that I actually don't need a totally precise ordering, since I will be then splitting the ordered data into K bins and assuming each object within the bin is roughly similar in it's "competitive ability".

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you determine which team "wins"?  Is there possibly a way of giving each team some kind of "awesomeness score" and using that to determine wins and losses?

Comment: Not really, the outcome at this point is binary. There are some other data I could possibly incorporate that might help me assess "speed" of victory, but I don't think these data are actually useful at predicting overall winning ability.

Comment: Without knowing more about how winning is assessed, I don't know that we can come up with a way of short-circuiting the calculation to avoid doing all the pairings.